# Boost linker Multi-threaded build issue

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2013

I've been using a successfully built boost library version 1.55.0 for a few weeks now but I ran into error `LNK1140 cannot open file 'libboost_filesystem-vc120-mt-sgd-1_55.lib` when I try using Multi-threaded(/MT) rather than /MD.
 I've been searching through forums and it seems that I need to statically link the library so I tried running `.\b2 --with-thread variant=release link=static threading=multi runtime-link=static` but that didn't work either.
 I have `C:/Boost/1.55.0/VC/12.0` in VC++ Directories->Include Directories and `C:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\12.0\stage\lib` in Linker->General->Additional Library Directories. Any ideas?

Comment: `variant=release,debug` - as you need the debug one (sgd).

Comment: So I ran cmd as admin, navigated to the boost directory, and then changed the script and ran it. It did build some stuff under threads and completed just fine. But when I tried to build my project I got the same missing file error. Am I missing a step?

Comment: I just noticed that you refer to `C:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\12.0\stage\lib`. Then append the word `stage` to your b2 line (I assume your Boost root directory is `C:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\12.0\`).

Comment: Correct my Boost root directory is C:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\12.0\stage\lib .Should I run the script inside C:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\12.0\stage\lib as well?

Comment: You should run it inside Boost root directory, i.e. `C:\Boost\1.55.0\VC\12.0\` . The `stage\lib` addition will be created during the build process.